# How to change selinux modes permissive to enforce in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: selinux

How to change selinux modes from permissive to enforcing in ubuntu 14.04.

I tried

```
# vim /etc/selinux/config
SELINUX=enforcing
save and quiet
# init 6
```

after that ... no luck.
when i execute `getenforce` command showing Disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Simply run `setenforce 1` as root. One way to do this is to run `sudo setenforce 1`.

You can verify that it succeeded by running `sestatus` and examining the output.

```
[root@ec2-54-183-55-79 filebeat]# setenforce 1
[root@ec2-54-183-55-79 filebeat]# sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      28
```

Answer (score -2):

How about this idea? Open a terminal

```
sudo -i
cd /etc/selinux/
gedit config
```

Here is what it looks like:

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
# enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
# permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
# disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=enforcing
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these two values:
# default - equivalent to the old strict and targeted policies
# mls     - Multi-Level Security (for military and educational use)
# src     - Custom policy built from source
SELINUXTYPE=ubuntu

# SETLOCALDEFS= Check local definition changes
SETLOCALDEFS=0
```

Make your changes and save as

Comment: That looks like what the OP did. I can confirm that setting `SELINUX=enforcing` and rebooting does not work.